# How to download and install spacy in conda

Tags: download, installation, spacy

```py
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

Gives me following error and I am not able to figure out why.

> Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
>   usage: `conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
>   conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: spacy`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`conda install -c spacy spacy`